# How to get 'div' shaped as a flag with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I want to add a label on some of my elements on a website and design for a label that is a flag with an inverted V-shaped cut at the bottom.

So far I have this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="css-shapes"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.css-shapes{
    border-left: 99px solid #f00fff;
    border-right: 99px solid #f00fff;
    border-bottom: 39px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhexkm4u/2/

However, I need the background to be white and border around this shape in purple and 1px. I was trying to fit the same shape just in white inside of this one, but everything got messy and didn't go as expected.

Maybe it is a wrong approach, but I want to end up with labels that would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Well it is included :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a slightly different method using [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) rotations to create an outlined banner like this:

[image: Before overflow cut]

- This angled shape is created with `position: absolute` pseudo-elements, `:before` and `:after`:

[image: Before overflow cut]

- The excess is cut off with `overflow: hidden` on the parent to form our banner:

[image: After overflow cut]

- The outline is created with `box-shadow` and the two angles are prevented from overlapping by pulling / pushing the x-axis by 46px — `box-shadow: 46px 0 0 3px #000`

### Full Example

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  box-shadow: 46px 0 0 3px #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: -120%;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  left: -120%;
  box-shadow: -46px 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: How can I remove dotted lines?

Answer (score 11):

**With CSS:**

You can use [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on pseudo elements to create the background with a **transparent inverted triangle** at the bottom:

```css
body{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');background-size:cover;}
p{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top:3px solid #EF0EFE;
}
p:before, p:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  height: 100%; width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  border:2px solid #EF0EFE;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p:before{
  left: 0;  
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  border-width:0 0 4px 3px;
}
p:after{
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  border-width:0 3px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text ... </p>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes on the `transform` and `transform-origin` properties to maximize browser support. See [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for more information.*

---

**With SVG**

Another approach is to use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) with the polygon element:

```css
body{background: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');background-size: cover;}
div{position: relative;width: 100px; height: 150px;}
svg{position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: -1;}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="-1.5 -1.5 103 153">
    <polygon points="100 0, 100 100, 50 85, 0 100, 0 0" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3" stroke="#ef0efe"/>
  </svg>
  <p>Some text ... </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**[STOLEN FROM CSS-SHAPES](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#Flag)**

```
#flag {
  width: 110px;
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #eee;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
}
```

DEMO:

```css
#flag {
  width: 110px;
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #eee;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag"></div>
```

---

## My Approach

My approach uses skewed elements, and allows you to quickly position them to your needs.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 10px solid tomato;
  border-top: 10px solid tomato;
  border-right: 10px solid tomato;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: -10px; /*width of border*/
  bottom: -30px;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-20deg);
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid tomato;
  border-left: 10px solid tomato;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -10px; /*width of border*/
  bottom: -30px;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid tomato;
  border-right: 10px solid tomato;
}
div:hover, div:hover:before, div:hover:after{
  background:lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<div>TEXT</div>
```

Comment: your approach works better - especially if you want the flag to be transparent (with opacity) - in case you want to put it e.g. over an image

Answer (score 2):

I've had a go at updating your CSS to create the effect you want:

```css
.css-shapes {
  height: 250px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 99px solid #f00fff;
  border-right: 99px solid #f00fff;
  border-bottom: 39px solid transparent;
  position: relative
}
.n-shape {
  height: 248px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 95px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 95px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 39px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -95px;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 198px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f00fff;
  left: -99px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-shapes">
  <div class="n-shape"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dywhjwna/

Comment: Awesome! Added few tweaks on sizes(to make it smaller for actual website) and looks like charm!! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround is to rotate it:

```
 transform: rotate(90deg);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/yhexkm4u/3/)

---

Another solution would be an SVG path, [here's a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/yhexkm4u/8/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, at first I added wrong fiddle link. No need to rotate in the case you checked, enough to change exchange border property values between right and bottom. Thanks for intentions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with.

[Link Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arnaudbertrand/yhexkm4u/6/)

It correspond to what you were looking for however I guess there should be a "better way" to it rather than playing with border.

HTML

```
<div id="text-div">
    Text
</div>
<div id="pacman">
    <div id="left-triangle"></div>
    <div id="right-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#text-div {
    width: 118px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#pacman { 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px;
    border-right: 60px solid purple; 
    border-top: 0px; 
    border-left: 60px solid purple; 
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}

#left-triangle{
    position: relative;
    left: -59px;
    border-right: 58px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 0px; 
    border-left: 58px solid white; 
    border-bottom: 58px solid transparent;
}
#right-triangle{
    position: relative;
    top: -59px;
    left: -57px;
    border-right: 58px solid white;
    border-top: 0px; 
    border-left: 58px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 58px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution with text easily positioned in the middle, using a rectangle background and a triangle at the bottom.

```css
.css-shapes{ 
  position: relative;
  height: 250px; 
  width: 150px; 
  background: #FFD05B;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:225px;
  font-size: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.css-shapes:after{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #fff;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-shapes">1</div>
```