# Remove Dotted Line

Tags: css

I follow this link [How to get 'div' shaped as a flag with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932080/how-to-get-div-shaped-as-a-flag-with-css) but now I can't remove dotted line. The code:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  box-shadow: 46px 0 0 3px #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: -120%;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  left: -120%;
  box-shadow: -46px 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the methods in the other answers in the question you linked to?

Comment: I can not see any dotted line?

Comment: [Aliased vs Anti-aliased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA7uy.png)

Comment: I cannot see a "dotted line." Are you referring to the rough edge on the angles?

Comment: I just compared the fiddle and your image, try in another browser and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `background: #fff` seems to fix the issue. Apply `z-index: -1` too, so that the content isn't covered by the `:before` and `:after` now that they're not transparent.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  box-shadow: 46px 0 0 3px #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: -120%;
  /* Setting the background
     covers the "dotted line" */
  background: #fff;
  /* It also covers the content
     so we need to move it underneath
     with z-index */
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  left: -120%;
  box-shadow: -46px 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```